# Help identifying this header/connector

Tags: identification, header

Is anyone able to identify the header and housing used here?

[image: Photo of mystery header]

It's used on the board in 2, 3, and 6 pin variations

Comment: Looks like Phoenix Euroblock. Can you add dimensions and pitch?

Comment: It looks like a standard terminal block. These are made by pretty much any manufacturer, for example Phoenix Contract MSTB family. In order to answer more precisely, we must know the connector pitch however. I can't tell if it is 5mm or 3.5mm. 5.08mm is another less common possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to both @winny and @Lundin - it's a 5.08mm pitch [Euroblock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euroblock).